# How can I traverse that nodes graph to generate code?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a graph with those connected nodes:

[image]

How can I traverse this graph to generate code like this:

```
function:  
  fun1()
  local cond = false
  ::branch_tag::
  if (cond) {
     fun2()
     return
  } else {
     cond = true
     goto branch_tag
  }
end
```

Comment: How is your graph represented (data structure), and with which language will you traverse it?

Comment: I will use C/C++, I don't have yet the data structure coded. Just first trying to figure how to solve the traverse problem before implement it. But I suppose I will have a Node struct with a set of ins and outs and the type of node.

Comment: So you'll follow the outs, mark nodes as visited, and when you arrive at a visited node, you know you have to use a goto/label.